# LOVE2D game engine ; 2D platformer collision systems

Tags: lua, 2d, love2d

I have attached 2 photos below. Currently I'm working on simple 2d platformer game; the idea is the player starts from left corner of the screen and if player captures the flag on the right corner of screen player wins and will take the player to the next level.

So I have my player and the ground set up and I applied the gravity and collision bounds to them (picture 1 reflects the situation). Anyways, here's the tricky part, how do I add the collision system to platform1, 2, and 3? **I didn't want to use "Tiled Map Editor" or such.** Goal is to create the levels using Photoshop & Illustrator and bring those to the game world.

Any thoughts and ideas? Or any advise?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is the platform different from another ground?

Comment: I could do same as the ground but I'm looking to design the level using Photoshop ; create platform 1,2,3 and bring those to the game scene and have them collision applied

Comment: so you want rectangles drawn with white pixels in the background image to become physics bodies without having to write their locations and sizes explicitly?

Comment: Sorry if my question was confused, and Yes almost but not automatically though.. Looking to find the better way of coding..I thought there would be a certain way to do it more efficiently .

Comment: The image above is just my prototype and my partner is working on game level & design using Photoshop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to create a file for each level specifying the location and sizes of the platforms and anything else like background image start location etc. Then work on coding the logic to load that data file and create the physics bodies etc. for the level from there.

an example data file might look like

```
 return {platforms={
             {x=200, y=200, width=10, height=20},
             {x=200, y=200, width=10, height=20},
             {x=200, y=200, width=10, height=20, type="brick"},
         },
         size={width=300,height=200},
         start={x=100,y=200},
         goal={x=200,y=100, nextlevel="desert"},
         background={image="bluelevel.png"}
 }
```

And then process these files to create the levels in a generic way:

```
function load_level(filename)
   data = dofile(filename)
    platforms = {}
    for i, p in ipairs(data.platforms) do
        body=love.physics.newBody(world, p.x, p.y, "static")
        shape=love.physics.newRectangle(p.width, p.height)
        fix=love.physics.newFixture(body, shape)
        platforms[i] = {body=body, shape=shape, fix=fix}
    end
    -- .... finish loading data
end
```